# apache httpcomponents digest authentication failes, old httpclient works

Tags: tomcat, httpclient, httpurlconnection, digest-authentication, apache-httpcomponents

I have a solr server that I secured with digest authentication in the web.xml, and I need to call solr from java.
I read tons of threads today and did many examples but no luck.

I have this code with commons-httpclient 3.1 that works and I'm getting 200 OK.

```
    URL url = new URL(solrUrl);

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
    httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), AuthScope.ANY_SCHEME),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(solrUrl);
    int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
    System.out.println(responseCode);
```

But when I try to do it with apache httpcomponent 4.2.2 I always get a 401 unauthorized.
this is almost identical to the official example.

```
       DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(solrUrl);
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getProtocol());
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password);
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(),targetHost.getPort()),
                creds);


        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(solrUrl);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost,httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        httpget.releaseConnection();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally
    {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

I also tried to do it with HttpUrlConnection and getting the same 401 allways.

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
            System.out.println("calling solr with user:pass " + pa.getUserName() + ":******");
            return pa;
        }
    };

    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(solrUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("type", "submit");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.connect();
    System.out.println( conn.getResponseCode());


        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue)
    {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to use apache httpcomponents 4 because of classpath issues, I'm in the process of giving up..

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my self:
Apparently I've hit a combination of jdk + tomcat bugs:

[java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8010505)

[tomcat bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54060)

it happened with jdk 1.6.0_45-b06 and tomcat 7.0.34, upgrade tomcat to 7.0.41 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I've been stressing over this for the past two days and all I needed was to get the latest tomcat.